# Resizing an Image HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I haven't been able to figure out how to resize my image on my HTML, but I am using a Style.css document to do all of that. What is the general code or method I should use in order to resize an image?

I looked up things on W3Schools and I have been able to resize my images on the HTML Document itself but since that is a type of styling I need to be able to do that on my style document and not on my HTML document.

Comment: Post a [mcve] and see [ask] please

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to resize an image in CSS? How exactly are you currently able to resize it?

Answer (score 1):

In your css file you could use width and height to resize an image looking like:

```
img {
width: 50%;
height: auto;
}
```

Additionally you could use the px value to set the exact dimensions of what size you would like your image to appear.